# How to change the user display name to their first name in Django

Tags: python, django, django-users

I am using the Django inbuilt user authentication system, from `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`. And I have realised that in the admin page it always displays the username of the user. Is it possible to change the `def __str__ (self):` method of that function to display a customized one, something like this.

```
def __str__ (self):
    return f"{self.first_name}"
```

Comment: Please reformat your question and add maybe a screenshot of what part of the admin you want to change? Because it shows first name in my admin landing page and not username.

Comment: if you want to show that name anywhere except django admin panel. use `user.firat_name`. but for more coding as django doc says you should override a user model over djangos user model and then override the __str__ method of that class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly recommend to [*extend the auth user model*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) and thus you can do *a lot of customizations* sooner or later.

---

You can use ***`lambda`*** function to alter the **`__str__()`** method of auth user as

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

User.__str__ = lambda user_instance: user_instance.first_name
```

*Note: This snippet should get executed on the Django server initialization*

If you are trying to change the *username* which is shown at the top-right-corner (as mentioned by [@amit sigh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65546636/how-to-change-the-user-display-name-to-their-first-name-in-django/65546738?noredirect=1#comment115886268_65546738) ), set the lambda function for **`get_short_name`** as,

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

User.get_short_name = lambda user_instance: f"Prefix : {user_instance.first_name} : Suffix"
```

Comment: I don't think extending the User model would help in this particular usecase.

Comment: Can you explain why?? OP wants to customize the `__str__()` of the ***built-in `User` model*** (isn't it?) extending  the model ***definitely*** give you more control over your models @AmitSingh

Comment: OP wants to change the name shown at the top right corner of the admin console page. And extending the User model won't help with that.

Comment: that top-r-c thing didn't come up in my mind, that's also a possibility, but he OP bit confusing though. Also, I strongly disagree with your argument *"extending the User model won't help with that"*, because, you will be able to *override* the `get_short_name` method in your custom model and Django will use the custom method instead of built-in @AmitSingh

Comment: You don't need to override the `get_short_name` because it returns the first name, in it's implementation. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_short_name

Comment: What if I want to display ***WELCOME, Mr/Mrs {first_name}***?

Comment: That would obviously mean changing the template too, if you want to add that customization but the OP has asked only about returning the first name. Also, I would not suggest overriding a function that has been documented to return first name to suddenly start returning "Welcome, Mr/Mrs {first name}" that would be bad programming. But yes, it would require changes in the user model too.

Comment: *"OP has asked only about returning the first name"*: I would rather read it as *"customizing the representation"* not just *returning the firstname*. I don't see any *bad programming* when I override things, because I need the changes in my project

Comment: You are trying to override the `User.get_short_name` in your answer which is bad programming. Extending it to another model and then overriding is something I would totally agree upon, but the correct suggested solution is bad programming.

Comment: Customizing the representation would definitely need help with extension of the model, true.

Comment: Well what I wanted was to change the display name of the user in the admin panel and it helped by doing `User.__str__ = lambda user_instance: user_instance.first_name`. Thanks a lot for all your help and efforts!

Answer (score 4):

For any such changes, you should refer to the template that's rendering it. Here, it is the Django Admin's `base.html` template.

As you can see in [this line in the file](https://github.com/django/django/blob/060e6bdd1f96f46d43fa34636284c20525a96f20/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html#L40), it searches for both `short_name` and `user_name` in that order and displays the first one available.

```
{% block welcome-msg %}
    {% translate 'Welcome,' %}
    <strong>
        {% firstof user.get_short_name user.get_username %}
    </strong>.
{% endblock %}
```

And [`get_short_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_short_name) returns the first name of the user. So, your user does not have their first name defined and hence it's showing up their username.

**NOTE** : Please check your Django version's documentation since this has been implemented after version 1.5 and above, and is valid only for greater versions.